# Racket latency with rsound

Tags: racket, latency

I wrote this program in Racket which generates 32 random notes from a set of 15 notes and then plays them. The duration of each note should be 0.25 seconds. When I run it gives latency which makes the melody sound off-beat.

How can it run normally?

This is the program:

```
#lang racket
(provide (all-defined-out))
(require rsound)
(require rsound/piano-tones)


(define-syntax-rule (note y x)
    (begin
       (play (piano-tone y))
       (sleep x)
       (stop)))

(define (random-element list)
  (list-ref list (random (length list))))

(define-syntax-rule (random-note)
  (note (random-element '(40 42 43 45 47 48 50 52 54 55 57 59 60 62 64)) 0.25))


(for ([i 32])
  (random-note))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the notes that come from [`piano-tone`](http://pkg-build.racket-lang.org/doc/rsound/index.html#%28mod-path._rsound%2Fpiano-tones%29) are not really meant to be truncated like that, although you can do it with the [`clip`](http://pkg-build.racket-lang.org/doc/rsound/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._rsound%2Fmain..rkt%29._clip%29%29) function.

Second of all, your problem here is that you are relying on how fast your computer will execute code, which is inherently inconsistent.

A much better approach is to use [`make-pstream`](http://pkg-build.racket-lang.org/doc/rsound/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._rsound%2Fmain..rkt%29._make-pstream%29%29). And to queue up the notes to run later. That way there won't be a gap based on your processor in between when notes play.

(Also, as a side note [`in-range`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-range#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-range%29%29) can be used to speed up for loops when you are using them like this.)

Put it all together (using clip to cut your notes off), your program will look something like this (I used magic numbers for brevity, obviously you would want to run through the actual calculations to get 0.25 seconds):

```
#lang racket

(require rsound
         rsound/piano-tones)

(define stream (make-pstream))

(define count 10000)
(define (note y x)
  (pstream-queue stream (clip (piano-tone y) 0 10000) count)
  (set! count (+ count x)))

(define (random-element list)
  (list-ref list (random (length list))))

(define (random-note)
  (note (random-element '(40 42 43 45 47 48 50 52 54 55 57 59 60 62 64)) 10000))

(for ([i (in-range 32)])
  (random-note))
```

Finally, if you want to wrap this all up into a single executable, the program will terminate before the queue finishes. So make a busy loop at the end of your program that waits for the queue to finish (by using [`pstream-queue-callback`](http://pkg-build.racket-lang.org/doc/rsound/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._rsound%2Fmain..rkt%29._pstream-queue-callback%29%29)).

Add this to the end of your program:

```
(define ok-to-exit? #f)
(pstream-queue-callback stream (lambda () (set! ok-to-exit? #t)) count)

(let loop ()
  (sleep 0.1)
  (unless ok-to-exit?
    (loop)))
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I have a different problem. I transformed it in an executable and it exits before all the for loop is being run. What can I do for all the notes to be played?

Comment: What's going on there is most likely that make-pstream is happening in a different thread, and the main thread isn't waiting for it to finish before it quits. Probably the easiest way to fix this is to add a `pstream-queue-callback` at the end of your song that signals when the program can end. I'll ad this to the answer.

Comment: (Also, you could just `sleep`, but that may finish before your program finishes playing.

Comment: I know, I know, I'm not supposed to make +1 comments, but *thank you* Leif for your lovely answer to this question.

Comment: Minorly wrong: a for loop with a literal number is just as fast since it is detected by the macro; Majorly wrong: any kind of solution that uses a busy-wait loop.